# How to set a display name to a custom variable in Grafana dashboard?

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

There is an option to create custom variables and give CSV values for them which appear in the drop-down selection of Grafana Dashboard. These variables become the input to the queries which are templatized. Sometimes, the variable values are not readable but they mean something. Example: If a dashboard is displaying stats of a city then the queries would have a condition like `city_id: $city_id` where `$city_id` is replaced by the custom variable which represents the city id 12345. Instead of having to display the id (12345), I want to display the names of the cities like Bengaluru, Mumbai, Delhi, etc

Comment: [Corresponding issue](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/1032) in Grafana's GitHub.

Answer (score 14):

- go to `Dashboard -> Settings -> JSON Model`
- find `templating` section and the variables you defined
- modify the `text` field for the variable whose display name you want to change
  [image]

Answer (score 5):

This option is not available on the dashboard configuration screen. But, if you see the JSON Model of the dashboard and see the `templating` section there is a list of options where the variables are defined. It has a `text` and `value` field. You can modify the `text` field to set the display name. Save the changes and refresh your dashboard, the changes will be reflected.